# checkbox images switch how?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have created a checkbox and want that when using all images change to other images, is such a thing possible?

I have created a checkbox and want that when using all images change to other images, is such a thing possible?

Comment: Please don't just repeat text - use the additional space allowed to describe the problem in more detail. In particular you must put the relevant code you have so far into your question with an explanation of exactly what is required and what isn't currently working. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.